# Bordes a filas en phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hola necesito saber como ponerle bordes a las filas, actualmente solo se lo pude poner a los nombres de las columnas, como puedo hacerlo.

Estoy trabajando con `PHPExcel`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
     if ($result > 0)
      {
          //TODOS LOS TEXTOS CENTRADOS
          $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($style);


          //ANCHO DE COLUMNAS
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(15);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(15);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(20);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(30);

//NOMBRES DE LAS COLUMNAS    

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A7', 'DESCRIPTION');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A7')->applyFromArray($estilo);


          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B7', 'OUTPUT QTY');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("B7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C7', 'REORDER LEVEL');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("C7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D7', 'TARGET STOCK');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("D7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E7', 'AREA');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("E7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F7', 'CATEGORY');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G7', 'EMPLOYEE');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("G7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G7')->applyFromArray($estilo);

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H7', 'OBSERVATIONS');
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("H7")->getFont()->setBold(true);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H7')->applyFromArray($estilo);
          $arraycount=count($result);
          $i=0;
          $total=0;
          while ($i < $arraycount)
          {
            $j=$i+8;

           //INFORMACION DE LAS FILAS
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$j, $result[$i]['description_item']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $result[$i]['quantity_s']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$j, $result[$i]['reorder_level']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$j, $result[$i]['target_Stock']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$j, $result[$i]['name_location']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F'.$j, $result[$i]['name_category']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G'.$j, $result[$i]['employee']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$j, $result[$i]['observations']);
            $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función setBorderStyle de phpecxel solo le agregas la propiedad PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN

Aquí un ejemplo para el borde inferior que seria getBottom:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("H7")->getBorders()
            ->getBottom()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
```